# Routing error after upgrading sf 5.4 to sf 6.X

Tags: php, symfony

After upgrading Symfony 5.4.10 to Symfony 6.0.0, i have this error is :

```
App\Kernel::configureRoutes(): Argument #1 ($routes) must be of type Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollectionBuilder, Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator\RoutingConfigurator given, called in /vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php on line 210
```

Kernel.php:46 :

```
    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes): void
```

MicroKernelTrait.php:210 :

```
        $configureRoutes->getClosure($this)(new RoutingConfigurator($collection, $kernelLoader, $file, $file, $this->getEnvironment()));
```

Comment: Symfony has been tweaking the micro kernel trait with the goal of having an empty App/Kernel class.  Makes things easier for Symfony to update.  Start by commenting out your App\Kernel\configureRoutes method completely and then use `debug:router` to see if you still have all your expected routes.  If you do then great, problem solved.  If not then copy the configureRoutes method from the trait to your kernel and then adjust to get your routes to load.  Repeat the process for configureContainer as well.

Comment: By the way, did you run `composer recipes:update` as part of your upgrade process?  In most cases it would have taken care of this problem for you. https://symfony.com/blog/fast-smart-flex-recipe-upgrades-with-recipes-update

Comment: No files were changed as a result of the update.

-- EDIT Thx @Cerad, comment and debug resolved this problem.